# Postman couldn't found in Unity launcher - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: launcher

I was trying to install Postman native app on Ubuntu 16.04 from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996358/how-to-install-start-postman-native-v4-10-3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-64-bit/43723749) and I installed it. But I couldn't get my Postman in Unity launcher. I've to run 
the `postman` command from the terminal to open it.

When I search it in my Unity launcher, there no application called Postman, then how it opens from the terminal?

Please help me with this to get Postman in Unity launcher.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By what you say, you seem to be missing the desktop entry for your postman application (which, in fact, is already explained in the post you gave).

You only need to add the `Postman.desktop` entry file on your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory (or in the `/usr/share/applications/` if you want it to be available for all users) and then reindex desktop entries (you can do so with <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> + <kbd>Intro</kbd>).

If the desktop entry file is correct, it should appear in your Unity panel.